# Emacs24 - Case insensitive auto-complete M-x load-file

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, elisp, emacs24, dotfiles

What setting has to be set in Emacs24 to make the `load-file` command to be case insensitive?

Comment: I typed `M-x find-function RET load-file RET` and took a look at the function consisting of 7 lines, including the doc-string and a comment.  It uses the function `read-file-name`, which I then Googled **read-file-name case insensitive auto-complete** and came up with the variable `read-file-name-completion-ignore-case` mentioned in the manual at the following link:  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Completion-Options.html  That variable can be set globally, or `load-file` can be revised with an `advice`, or create a new or revised function by let-binding the variable.

Comment: Note that Emacs has a built-in searching mechanism for useful terms and such -- e.g., apropos -- but I'm kind of lazy and like Google better.  Here is the link to the section on apropos:  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Apropos.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything directly built in, but all the standard Elisp files have lowercase names, so if that's all you need to cope with, you could do something like

```
(defadvice load-file (around lowercase-argument activate compile)
  "Call `downcase' on the FILE argument to `load-file'."
  (let ((file (downcase file)))  
    ad-do-it))
```